# How do you split a long string into two smaller strings, about the space character closest to the string's center?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have some string

```
str_0 = "This is a very long string that I would like to split into two shorter strings"
```

Is there a way that I can split this string into two based on the `" "` (space) character closest to the center? In the case of this string I would have

```
str_1 = "This is a very long string that I would"
str_2 = "like to split into two shorter strings"
```

Comment: what do you do if the two spaces are equally apart from the mid point, like this: `how are you`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not complete in the sense that a symmetric sentance would require a choice. For example `how are you` has two equal spaces either side of the 'middle'.

If the choice for a symmetric find is the **first space**, then you can split like this:

```py
str_0="This is a very long string that I would like to split into two shorter strings"


def split_string(str_0):
    ''' function to split string by closest space'''

    mid_point = int(len(str_0)/2)

    if str_0[mid_point]==' ':
        # the middle point is a space
        str_1 = str_0[:mid_point]
        str_2 = str_0[mid_point+1:]
        return str_1, str_2


    for i in range(1,mid_point):
        # the middle point is a character
        if str_0[mid_point-i] == ' ':
            break_point = mid_point-i
            break

        if str_0[mid_point+i] == ' ':
            break_point = mid_point+i
            break

    str_1 = str_0[:break_point]
    str_2 = str_0[break_point+1:]
    return str_1, str_2


r = split_string(str_0)
print(r[0])
print(r[1])
```

the result is this:

```
This is a very long string that I would
like to split into two shorter strings
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
>>> str_0 = "This is a very long string that I would like to split into two shorter strings"
>>> words = str_0.split()
>>> words
['This', 'is', 'a', 'very', 'long', 'string', 'that', 'I', 'would', 'like', 'to',
 'split', 'into', 'two', 'shorter', 'strings']
>>> k = len(words)//2 + 1
>>> ' '.join(words[:k])
'This is a very long string that I would'
>>> ' '.join(words[k:])
'like to split into two shorter strings'
```

Comment: Suspect result with `str_0 = 'I am not a hippopotamus'`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of the character in the middle, then advance the index until you find a space. Finally, slice your string.

```
i = len(str_0) // 2
while str_0[i] != ' ':
    i += 1

str_1 = str_0[:i]
str_2 = str_0[i+1:]
```

Note that this does not actually get the space closest to the center.  Rather it grabs the first space at or after the midpoint. If that's an actual requirement use [`textwrap.wrap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

```
import textwrap

width = len(s) // 2
while len(result:=textwrap.wrap(s, width)) > 2:
    width += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would search outward from the center for a space, and return the halves as a tuple.

```py
def splitter(longstring) -> (str,str):
   mid = len(longstring) // 2
   for i in range(mid):
      if longstring[mid + i] == ' ':
          # Note the '+1' to elide the space from the second half.
          return longstring[:mid+i], longstring[mid+i+1:]
      elif longstring[mid - i] == ' ':
          return longstring[:mid-i], longstring[mid-i+1:]
   # In the edge case we return the entire string in the first element of the tuple.
   return longstring, ''
```

Some samples sample demonstrating the usage

```py
samples= [
       "This is a very long string that I would like to split into two shorter strings",
       "This is a very long string that I wouldliketosplitinto two shorter strings",
       "This is a very long string thatIwouldliketo split into two shorter strings",
       "This isaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstrings",
       "ThisisaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstring s",
       "ThisisaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstrings"]

for long in samples:
   print(long)
   left, right = splitter(long)
   print(f"A: {left} ({len(left)} chars)")
   print(f"B: {right} ({len(right)} chars)")
   print("-----------")
```

This produces output like:

```
This is a very long string that I would like to split into two shorter strings
A: This is a very long string that I would (39 chars)
B: like to split into two shorter strings (38 chars)
-----------
This is a very long string that I wouldliketosplitinto two shorter strings
A: This is a very long string that I (33 chars)
B: wouldliketosplitinto two shorter strings (40 chars)
-----------
This is a very long string thatIwouldliketo split into two shorter strings
A: This is a very long string thatIwouldliketo (43 chars)
B: split into two shorter strings (30 chars)
-----------
This isaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstrings
A: This (4 chars)
B: isaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstrings (59 chars)
-----------
ThisisaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstring s
A: ThisisaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstring (62 chars)
B: s (1 chars)
-----------
ThisisaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstrings
A: ThisisaverylongstringthatIwouldliketosplitintotwoshorterstrings (63 chars)
B:  (0 chars)
-----------
```

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you cannot split it using based on space character closest to center, you can directly split it from centre using this

```
str_0 = "This is a very long string that I would like to split into two shorter strings"
str1 = str_0[0:len(str_0)//2]
str2 = str_0[len(str_0)//2:]
print(str1)
print(str2)
```